# squid v5.5 is not logging successful ssh connections on oracle linux 9.2

Tags: squid

I adjusted my acls to allow port 22 traffic, however my access log is not showing succsssful port 22 connections only denys and the "denys" show a http RC of 200.
access.log is below

```
[20/Sep/2023:08:11:50 -0400]      0 192.168.xx.xx - - "CONNECT ho-lx-sys-xxx:22 HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "-" TCP_DENIED:HIER_NONE - - -

Here are my tests:
ssh -vvv dbsmith@ho-lx-sys-xxx -o "ProxyCommand=nc -x 192.168.xx.xx:8888 %h %p"
Executing proxy command: exec nc -x 192.168.xx.xx:8888 ho-lx-sys-xxx 22
...
Authenticated to ho-lx-sys-xxx (via proxy).

telnet 192.168.xx.xx 8888
Trying 192.168.xx.xx...
Connected to 192.168.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECT ho-lx-sys-xxx:22 HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

My logformat is:

```
[%tl] %6tr %>a %[ui %[un "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %>Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh %mt %<pt %<tt
```

Any ideas as why squid is not logging my successful attempts? Is this normal? I see other successful connections however those are on port 443.  Thank you!